# Internet Explorer not handling transparency using jQuery Cycle plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, jquery-cycle

I am running the jQuery Cycle plugin and noticing that IE is applying background colors to what should be transparent elements. I assume this is part of IE's terribly handling of PNGs and alpha transparency, but I'm not entirely certain as to whether I should be trying to modify the plugin or simply scrap it in favor of something that has no IE quirks.

Comment: Adding the html and javascript code, which you are using, may help people understand your problem better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would help : http://www.workingconcept.com/blog/entry/internet-explorer-jquery-cycle-plugin-background-issue

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I was positive it was IE's terrible handling of PNGs and alpha channel transparency but not sure if it was going to be worth trying to modify the plugin behavior or scrap it in favor some something within the time and money allocated to the project.